# Docker-compose link containers in settings file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have following docker-compse.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  api:
     build: api/.
     command: make run
     depends_on:
       - postgres
     links:
       - postgres:postgres
  processor:
     build: processor/.
     command: make run
     ports:
       - "9000:9000"
     links:
       - api:api
```

In my processor I have following setting.ini:

```
api=http://api:7000/
```

And Dockerfile for processor looks like following:

```
ADD ./src/processor/setting.ini /etc/app/processor/setting.ini
```

When running this via `docker-compose up` I got errors that processor couldn't see the api. Is it possible to link them?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just add the link to your processor service:

```
version: '2'
services:
  api:
    build: api/.
    command: make run
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    links:
      - postgres:postgres
  processor:
    build: processor/.
    links:
      - api:api
    command: make run
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
```

I moved your `links` section directly into your definition of `processor`. This is where links should be defined (see [Compose File Reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/links)).

Comment: I fixed it as you said but error still persist: `processor_1           | ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known))`